# How to find exact match records with no duplicate in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

How can I find the exact match in case of duplicate values in tables I am using the below query to find users which are having write access based on the below values.
Note - Each customer can have multiple users
`Example - user **A write** user - {UI.ACCESS, API.ACCESS} and`
`user **B read** user - {UI.ACCESS, API.ACCESS, UI.READONLY, API.READONLY}`
query should return only A user

> tried below way -

```
select  DISTINCT ul.ID from CUSTOMER cus join USER_LOCAL ul on cus.ID = ul.CUSTOMER_ID

                                                  join USER_SECURITY_ROLE ur on ul.ID = ur.USER_ID
                                                  join SECURITY_ROLE_PERMISSION sr on ur.SECURITY_ROLE_ID = sr.SECURITY_ROLE_ID
                                                  join SECURITY_PERMISSION sp on sr.SECURITY_PERMISSION_ID = sp.ID
where sp.PERMISSION_NAME in ('UI.ACCESS','API.ACCESS') 
  and ul.ID not in
      (select  DISTINCT ul.ID from CUSTOMER cus join USER_LOCAL ul on cus.ID = ul.CUSTOMER_ID

                                                join USER_SECURITY_ROLE ur on ul.ID = ur.USER_ID
                                                join SECURITY_ROLE_PERMISSION sr on ur.SECURITY_ROLE_ID = sr.SECURITY_ROLE_ID
                                                join SECURITY_PERMISSION sp on sr.SECURITY_PERMISSION_ID = sp.ID
       where sp.PERMISSION_NAME in ('UI.READONLY','API.READONLY'));
```

is there any optimized way we can do it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a create table statement and sample data for all tables so people can assist you

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't 100% clear, but it seems like maybe you have a problem in your data model / application design.  Namely, the fact that "user A" has write access should not be indicated by the *absence* of a `UI.READONLY`/`API.READONLY` security permission.  Rather, there should be a `UI.WRITE`/`API.WRITE` permission that your query is looking for.

But assuming you can't fix that issue right now, you might try a query like this:

```
SELECT     ul.id
FROM       customer cus
INNER JOIN user_local ul ON ul.customer_id = cus.id
INNER JOIN user_security_role ur ON ur.user_id = ul.id
INNER JOIN security_role_permision sr ON sr.security_role_id = ur.security_role_id
INNER JOIN security_permission sp ON sp.id = sr.security_permission_id
WHERE      s.permission_name IN ('UI.ACCESS','API.ACCESS','UI.READONLY','API.READONLY')
GROUP BY   ul.id
HAVING     MAX(DECODE(sp.permission_name, 'UI.ACCESS', 1, 0) = 1
AND        MAX(DECODE(sp.permission_name, 'API.ACCESS', 1, 0) = 1
AND        MAX(DECODE(sp.permission_name, 'UI.READONLY', 1, 0) = 0
AND        MAX(DECODE(sp.permission_name, 'API.READONLY', 1, 0) = 0
```

This will give you the user IDs that have `UI.ACCESS` and `API.ACCESS`, but not either or both of `UI.READONLY` and `API.READONLY`.